# C# - Prototyping an object model to generate pages from a database

Tags: c#

I'm currently on a C# Web Dev course, and while I now have a decent understanding
of basic C#, I have been moved onto Object Oriented.

I have made a basic news website, with articles including text, images and titles.

Now with my C# work I have been asked to prototype an Object Model to allow the generation of new articles (title, image, text) from a database.

I'm still very new to OOP, so I've been 'thrown into the deep end of sorts'.

The specification I have been given is this:

"The basis of all our work is articles. All our articles have a title, one or more paragraphs of text, category and an image. We currently have the following categories: Local news; Sport.

All images have their own titles, descriptions and a filename. We also have a daily-mail style sidebar “of shame” – these have sidebar items consisting of images, titles and a single paragraph of text. Both articles and side-bar articles need a link address to the main article page and we need to be able to archive the articles so they are no longer displayed. The home page of our site consists of the current articles and a the sidebar, these both need to be ordered so we can display the most eye-catching articles first. 
Our sports page consists of all sport articles, a sport sidebar and a league table.

The league table consists of the Premier League, displaying the team name, games played, goal difference and the number of points the teams have so far this season. The league table should be sortable so it prints in the correct order (by Points, Goal Difference , Games played (lowest first) then alphabetically)."

Could anyone either work me through the steps, or provide some example code for me to base my work off?

Thanks, massively in advance, I've been stuck on this for a while now.

EDIT:

Article class:

```
class Article
{
    public string title { get; set; }
    public Image Image { get; set; }
    public string text { get; set; }
    public string articleLink { get; set; }
    public bool isArchived { get; set; }
}
```

}

Image Class:

```
class Image
{
    public string imgTitle { get; set; }
    public string imgDescription { get; set; }
    public string imgFileName { get; set; }
}
```

SidebarItems Class:

```
class sidebarItem
{
    public string sidebarTitle { get; set; }
    public Image sidebarImg { get; set; }
    public string sidebarText { get; set; }
    public string sideArticleLink { get; set; }
    public bool isArchived { get; set; }
}
```

Basically, the problem I'm having is how I would display an article in a 'HomePage' class, but these articles need to be displayed in a list; along with how exactly I can create a league table, I thought it would have been a dictionary with lists as value. This may be a simple problem but I can't figure it out for some reason..

Comment: _[Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've **done so far** to solve the problem, and a **description** of the **difficulty you are having** solving it.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)_. So far you have arguably just posted requirements.  Any code to show?  Thanks

Comment: Hi, I have added my classes.  My internet is having problems, so apologies for the late reply

Answer (score 0):

ok here's the article stuff. although the sidebar items are ambiguous in their spec I assume they want you to demonstrate inheritance

```
public enum category
{
    LocalNews,
    Sport
}


public class article
{
    public string id;
    public string title;
    public string body;
    public string imageId;
    public category category;
    public int eyecatchingness;
    public bool archived;

}

public class image
{
    public string id;
    public string title;
    public string description;
    public string filename;
}

public abstract class sidebarItem
{
    public string id;
    public category category;
    public string mainArticleId;
}
public abstract class sidebarItemImage : sidebarItem
{
    public string imageId;

}
public abstract class sidebarItemTitle : sidebarItem
{
    public string title;
}
public abstract class sidebarItemParagraph : sidebarItem
{
    public string paragraph;
}
```